# Caching/job tracking framework

Tags: java, caching, jobs

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

- I have some expensive work to do which I then cache the result of
- The work is keyed by a string
- Many requests may arrive simultaneously for the same key
- I'd like to avoid doing the work more than once per key
- I'd like to add callbacks against the key which will be invoked when the work is completed; not all of these are known when the work is first submitted.

This feels like a problem which ought to have been solved already; does anybody know of a Java framework or library which covers it?

Comment: First four seem pretty straightforward with whatever the Java equivalent of lock in C# is. Fifth probably possible with events.

Quartz might be helpful but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine a wrapper around guava's `LoadingCache` but I'm not aware of a library which does everything out of the box.

While `LoadingCache#get` is synchronous, it does get you 1-4 and there may be some mileage in using `refresh` which can return a `ListenableFuture` (although to get all the features you list it might become a fairly chunky wrapper?)

For Reference:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#refresh(K)

http://www.theotherian.com/2013/11/non-blocking-cache-with-guava-and-listenable-futures.html